# Android c header files include path

Tags: android, c++, path, header, include

I'm trying to port a c++ project with several files to android. I'm using the following directory structure:

/game
_ /source
_ _ /android
_ _ _ /jni
_ _ _ _ /game (symlink to the upper game folder)
_ _ /src (.cpp and .h files)

_ /thirdparty
_ _ /audio (.cpp and .h files)
_ _ /video (.cpp and .h files)

The problem I'm facing is that when I try to compile a cpp file in the jni/symlinked game folder, then it tries to include another header located in "../../thirdparty/" path, then the compiler gives me this: 
"jni/game/source/game/src/../../thirdparty/ fatal error"

How can I tell the compiler to follow the relative paths given in the #include "" tags?